# pandas loc search by part of a string not using regexp

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'name': ['HelloWorld', 'ByeWorld'],
        'physics': [22, 33],
        'chemistry': [44, 55]}

a = pd.DataFrame(data)

b = a.loc[a['name'] == 'Hello']

print(b)
```

This code would not return any rows, but I would like to achieve it would return the first row, because it includes "Hello". Is there any elegant solution to solve this with the loc command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

`b = a.loc[a['name'].str.contains('Hello')]`

also if your only looking at the start of a string you can use

`b = a.loc[a['name'].str.startswith('Hello')]`

Not

`b = a.loc[a['name'] == 'Hello']`

this line of code will only return True for a row containing ONLY `Hello`